# get count of relational table entry in symfony

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

How can I get the number of entries under each job. Let's take a jobeet tutorial, here I want to show number of resume submits for each job.

Tables

```
job : id  title      
submit : id job_id file
```

Result :

```
 title           submits    
 job a             5
 old job           20
```

I am using *Doctrine*. So, How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```
$job    = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Job')->find(1);

// it will query the database to fetch the relation
$submit = $job->getSubmit()->count();
```

But if you want something more specific, show us your `schema.yml.`

If you want to avoid un new query to the database, you can fetch the relation with a `leftJoin`:

```
$job    = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Job')
  ->leftJoin('Job.Submit')
  ->find(1);

// the relation is already fetched, so it won't perform a new query
$submit = $job->getSubmit()->count();
```

By the way, be careful with the `->count()` method, if you have a lot of submits, this query won't be really optimized. The best, is to perform a manual query count:

```
$submit = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Submit')
    ->createQuery('s')
    ->select('COUNT(s.id) as total')
    ->where('s.job_id = ?', array($job->getId()))
    // HYDRATE_NONE won't hydrate the return object 
    ->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_NONE);

// I guess the value is here but test yourself
var_dump($submit[0]);
```

Comment: This is awesome. I was looking for the same. Let me know How  getSubmit() works. Is this works because of relation between two tables or can i get count using this with any model. How can i check if i want only active submit only. like status = 'active'

Comment: It works because of the relation name between models. It will automatically load the relation for the Job 1. If you want to avoid a new query to the database, you can add the relation as a `leftJoin` in the query. I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for more explanation. But I don't understand where should i write this code and how to get the count in template.can you explain little further.I am waiting for you in [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19986/room-for-gowri-and-j0k), if you wish please come over here